# Angular2 / Typescript "map" two observables to one Interface

Tags: angular, rxjs, typescript2.0, angular2-observables

I have a small problem with the merge two data sources into one interface

There is a Interface

```
export interface IProvince {
  code: number;
  name: string;
  svgData: string;
  part: number;
  color: string;
}
```

Now I have two different data sources, one provides me data for fields: *[code, name, svgData, part]*, *[color]* is from another observable.

```
getAllProvince(): Observable<IProvince[]>
  {
    return <Observable<IProvince[]>>this.http
      .get('url')
      .map((response: Response) => <IProvince[]>response.
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .finally(() => {
        this.loader.complete();
        console.log("Data: ", this.provinceData);
      });

  }
  getLegendData(): Observable<ILegend[]> {
    return Observable.of(this.legendData);
  }

  getStyleColorData(part: number) {
    let color: ILegend;
    return this.getLegendData().subscribe((items: ILegend[]) => color = items.find(p => p.part == part));
  }
```

The problem is that at the moment I lack the data [color] I do not know how to "on the fly" to add the value from another function.

Here I have function: getStyleColorData(part: number) which should give me "color" after i pas [part] from [getAllProvince()].
Question: There is simple way to combine this two or maby I'm going in the wrong direction ?

Tx for answers and solutions :)

Comment: What is this.legendData? A simple array? How do you get a color string from an ILegend?

Comment: Now is Array, but shoud be another data from server. eg:   {
      part: 1,
      name: "Quantyl 1",
      color: "#B4572C"
    },

Answer (score 0):

If you have two Observables (e.g. from http requests, you can combine them with [`Observable.combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) or [`Observable.withLatestFrom`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md).

Try something like this:

```
getProvinces() {
  return this.http
    .get('url')
    .map(response => response.json() as IProvince[])
    .withLatestFrom(this.getLegendData(), (provinces, legendData) => ({provinces, legendData})
    .map(combined => combined.provinces.map(
            province => province.color = combined.legendData.find(legend => legend.part == province.part).color));
}

getLegendData() {
  return this.http
    .get('url2')
    .map(response => response.json() as ILegend[]);
}
```

Comment: I try this, but when do sth like thah:L  combineMapdata()
  {
    Observable.combineLatest(this.getAllProvince(), this.getLegendData()).subscribe((data: any[]): void => {
      console.log(data);
      // cassettes - data[0]
      // glass     - data[1]
    });
  }

ii got "console / server spam, request every second, i belive its sth with observables

Comment: I added an example, can you try if the problem persists when you try something like this?

Comment: Now is: (Property 'color' does not exist on type 'IProvince'.) I belive when i do "first map my color  stop exist in context,